# Uncaught TypeError: d3plus.Pie is not a constructor

Tags: d3.js, charts, d3plus

I want to make a Pie Chart based on d3plus library. I try with below code (But i have a problem, **d3plus.Pie is not a constructor**)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D3Plus</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3plus/1.9.8/d3plus.full.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <script>
            var myData = [
              {"Group": "Store", "Sub-Group": "Convenience Store", "Number of Food Stores": 100},
              {"Group": "Store", "Sub-Group": "Grocery Store", "Number of Food Stores": 150},
              {"Group": "Store", "Sub-Group": "Farmer's Market", "Number of Food Stores": 50},
              {"Group": "Store", "Sub-Group": "Supercenters", "Number of Food Stores": 30},
              {"Group": "Restaurant", "Sub-Group": "Fast-Food Restaurant", "Number of Food Stores": 60},
              {"Group": "Restaurant", "Sub-Group": "Full-Service Restaurant", "Number of Food Stores": 120}
            ];

            new d3plus.Pie()
              .config({
                data: myData,
                groupBy: ["Group", "Sub-Group"],
                value: function(d) {
                  return d["Number of Food Stores"];
                }
              })
              .render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting error : d3plus.Pie is not a constructor. Can someone please tell me my mistake or point me towards basic d3plus examples and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need a different source including hierarchy

```
https://d3plus.org/js/d3plus-hierarchy.v0.8.full.min.js"
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>D3Plus</title>
  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3plus.org/js/d3plus-hierarchy.v0.8.full.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <script>
            var myData = [
              {"Group": "Store", "Sub-Group": "Convenience Store", "Number of Food Stores": 100},
              {"Group": "Store", "Sub-Group": "Grocery Store", "Number of Food Stores": 150},
              {"Group": "Store", "Sub-Group": "Farmer's Market", "Number of Food Stores": 50},
              {"Group": "Store", "Sub-Group": "Supercenters", "Number of Food Stores": 30},
              {"Group": "Restaurant", "Sub-Group": "Fast-Food Restaurant", "Number of Food Stores": 60},
              {"Group": "Restaurant", "Sub-Group": "Full-Service Restaurant", "Number of Food Stores": 120}
            ];
            new d3plus.Pie()
              .config({
                data: myData,
                groupBy: ["Group", "Sub-Group"],
                value: function(d) {
                  return d["Number of Food Stores"];
                }
              })
              .render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

d3plus modules list can be found at
https://github.com/d3plus

Comment: Thank you verry much dear's. It work fine. But when i want to test for bar chart not work the same error above show. **barChart.html:28 Uncaught TypeError: d3plus.BarChart is not a constructor** if you have any idea about that help me please. I think in th script src i have a problem but i don t know  bye what i can replace src link for work with barchart

Comment: for the bar chart  you might need to link the original `d3-plus.full.js` look at the source code from view-source:https://d3plus.org/examples/d3plus-plot/bar-chart/

Comment: I try to link my html file with this scripts links below but not work, i am really sorry !!!                                           <script src="https://d3plus.org/js/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3plus.org/js/d3plus.min.js"></script>

Comment: @MohamedCherradi seems like they have specific bundles for each component here is the link `<script src="https://d3plus.org/js/d3plus-plot.v0.8.full.min.js"></script>`

Comment: look at their org, each component has a different module https://github.com/d3plus

Comment: @MohamedCherradi if that worked you can accept the answer! :)